# Introductory study of Survival Analysis and Decision Theory

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-theory, decision-theory

I want to focus myself on survival analysis and decision theory, and over this winter break I want to get a headstart on that before the next semester kicks in.
Please do me a favor, consider me a total noob and suggest introductory texts and resources that can help me start off.

Someone experienced with this, if you could guide me with a rough study plan with resources to refer to, I'd be eternally grateful. :)

Thanks!